# Nodejs can i save an array in my backend, and use it when i need it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a small website, when you go into it it'll show you a quote.

Till today what I was doing is, when a user goes to my website a random quote that directly comes from the database will be shown (when I say directly I mean a connection was made to the database and return a quote from it) but sometimes it took some time like 1 or 2 seconds, today I did something different when my nodejs application starts I grab every quote in the database and store them inside an Array. So when someone comes to my website I'll randomly choose a quote in the Array, and it was so much faster compared to the first way of doing it and I make some changes so when I add new quote to the database the Array automatically updated.

So here is my question, is it bad to store data inside an array and serve users with it?

Comment: What about using something like MongoDB to store your quotes and create via Node.JS a REST API endpoint (something link /quotes/random) which serve a random quote from the database to your front-end? If you only need a quote "per-user", returning a whole array of quotes it's unnecessary.

Comment: How can you tell when somebody adds an item to your list of quotes? Do you care about that?

Comment: @O.Jones no one can add quote except myself so there is no need for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a few different answer according to your intentions. First of all, if the dataset of quotes are a lot in quantity. I assure you it is a very bad idea but if you are talking about a few items. Well, it's acceptable. However, if you are building a scalable application, it's not much recommended because you will keep all copies of the dataset in each node etc.

If you want a very fast quote storage, I would recommend redis (a key value storage for RAM). It shares the state for each node which means your all nodes connect to redis and the quotes are kept in redis so that you do not need to keep the copies and it becomes fast. Also, if you activate the disk record option, you can use redis as your primary quote storage. In the end, you won't update these quotes too much and they won't be searched with a complex query.

Alternatively, if your database is mysql, postgre or mongodb, you can activate ram storage option so that you don't need to keep that data on your array but directly take it form db which is much more fast but also queryable.

Answer (score 1):

There's the old joke: The two hard things in software engineering are naming things, caching things, and off-by-one errors.

You're caching something: your array of strings. Then you select one at random from the array each time you need one.

What is right?  You get your text string from memory, and eliminate the time-delay involved in getting it from the database.  It's a good optimization.

What can go wrong?

1. Somebody can add or remove strings from your database, which makes your cache stale.
2. You can have so many text strings you blow out your nodejs RAM. This seems unlikely; it's hard to imagine a list of quotes that big. The Hebrew Bible, the New Testament, and the Qur'an together comprise less than a million words. You probably won't have more text in your quotable-quotes than that. 10-20 megabytes of RAM is nothing these days.

So, what about your stale cache in RAM? What to do?

- You could ignore the problem. Who cares if the cache is stale?
- You could reread the cache every so often.

Your use of RAM for this is a good optimization. But, it adds a cache to your application. A cache adds complexity, and the potential for a bug. Is the optimization worth the trouble? Only you can guess the answer to that question.

And, it's MUCH MUCH better than doing `SELECT ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;` every time you need something random. That is a notorious query-performance antipattern.

Comment: WOW, man amazing actually when ever a quote get added to the database the quote array will update automatically